# How to go to the Android's voice seach settings by intent?

Tags: android

I want to know if there is a way that can make going to the voice seach settings possible after clicking on a Button?

For example to go to the Location services we use : `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` .I search something like that about voice search Settings but I didn't find any thing.

Can someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,hope that can help :

Pre-Jelly Bean

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.voicesearch","com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences"));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Post-Jelly Bean the package name is different,so the code must be like that :

```
try {
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.voicesearch",
                            "com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

} catch (final Exception e) {

try {
final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences"));
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);

} catch (final Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```